# Qtip2 not fired for dynamically added controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamically-generated, qtip2

I have an application where I have one row of elements by default and has an add button to add rows dynamically.The rows are added using guid as unique identifier. I am using qtip to show the validation errors.However qtip is not fired for dynamically added rows. Kindly help.The following is my code.

> addNewIndentItem: function () {

```
    count++;
    alert("in add");
    alert(count);


    // generate a Guid value used to make the ID and NAME attributes unique for this row

    var guid = viewModel._generateGuid();
    alert(guid);
    document.getElementById('removeAnotherPhone').style.visibility = "visible";
    // using JSRENDER we get the template from the indentItemTemplate script object and replace all "index" with the guid value
    var html = $("#indentItemTemplate").render({ "index": guid });
    $("removeAnotherPhone").visible = "true";
    $("#tblIdentItems").append(html);

    // get references to the inputs that need work done to them
    var DepartmentMachineId = 'select[name="IndentItems[' + guid + '].DepartmentMachineId"]';


    var itemNameId = 'select[name="IndentItems[' + guid + '].ItemName"]';
    var CategoryNameId = 'select[name="IndentItems[' + guid + '].CategoryName"]';
    var ItemCodeId = 'select[name="IndentItems[' + guid + '].ItemId"]';
    var IssuedQuantity = 'input[name="IndentItems[' + guid + '].IssuedQuantity"]';



    // False means we are editing an indent so disable fields
    if ($("#IsCreate").val() == "False") {
        $(IssuedQuantity).blur(CalcBalance);
    }
    else {
        // configure the custom drop down for any rows of items that were created when the page was first generated
        alert("subsequent load");
        $(DepartmentMachineId);           
        $(itemNameId).change(GetItemCategories);
        $(CategoryNameId).chosen().change(GetItems);
        $(ItemCodeId).chosen().change(SetItem);           

    }
```

I have added a js file jquery.qtip.js which invokes the qtip for first time load

Comment: To bind dynamically created elements to events, you must use delegate instead of bind.

I'd suggest modifying the plugin code to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Can you please explain it a bit more or give me some links ?

Comment: After looking again, it says that it has been superseded by the .on() handler. Read it here, look for delegated events for an explanation: http://api.jquery.com/on/